# How to resize a rendered component in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web

I have this component on a react website I am working on. Its an iframe generated using walls.io.

[Wall](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWDnU.jpg)

This is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Home.css';

const Wall = ({src}) => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <iframe
                className="responsive-iframe"
                allowFullScreen id="wallsio-iframe"
                src={src}
                loading="lazy"
                title="My social wall">
            </iframe>

        </div>
    );
}

export default Wall;
```

I want to resize this component and add it to a card component. But when I do that, I want the entire component itself to be resized (the images and the text should become smaller) instead of the component's dimensions being changed.
This is the current state of the card :

[Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCxxu.png)

I want the entirety of the previous screen to fit inside this card. Is there any way to maybe "pre-render" a component or any other solutions? Thanks in advance. Apologies for the length of the question.

Comment: It looks like it is being resized. But an iframe scrollbar shows up by default - you can always turn it off. Also problematic that this is a component yet contains an id - it means you can't (shouldn't) reuse it. Noteworthy: `iframes` are pretty heavy for just displaying an image - are you sure you don't want to just display an image instead?

Comment: I am trying to get the media posts from my Instagram profile and show it as a grid on my website. I am using walls.io for the same. I looked into any API provided by Instagram and the only thing I found was Facebook Graph API which was really confusing. I am fairly new to this so I would appreciate any suggestions on how to achieve what I am going for.

Comment: And like you said, the component is being resized to some extent but I tried fiddling around a lot, and yet I can't seem to get the result I am hoping for. I want to have at least 4 posts to fit inside that card. I am trying to figure out if there is a way to have the contents of the iframe be shrunk along with the component.

Comment: `figure out if there is a way to have the contents of the iframe be shrunk along with the component` - answer: no. You (your component) can't control what's in the iframe. This is much better done with images. Iframes are the wrong direction.

Comment: I see. Thank you for your reply. I really appreciate it. But is there a way for the contents of the iframe remain the same but the component itself is reduced in size? What I mean by that is the component remains the same except the entirety of it gets reduced in size. I hope I am not being too confusing.

Answer (score 1):

**I am not sure this the solution you are looking for but anyways here it is:**

***try with css zoom property:***

```css
.container {
  width: 750px;   //you can always adjust
  height: 1500px; //you can always adjust
  padding: 0;     
  overflow: hidden;
}


.responsive-iframe {
  zoom: 0.75;
  -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
  -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -o-transform: scale(0.75);
  -o-transform-origin: 0 0;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
```

***If this seems relevant here is [full explanation](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-scale-the-content-of-iframe-element.html)***